# Excel - disable F11 keystroke

Tags: excel, vba

Switching back and forth between my IDE debugger and Excel, I am forever hitting F11 (next step in debugger) when Excel has the focus - and Excel creates a new chart (F11).

Is there any way to disable or reassign F11 in Excel? Does anyone know of a tool that will do it? I am ready to defenestrate Excel through the MS Windows.

Comment: Isn't F8 the default key for stepping through the debugger?

Comment: I use VSCode as my usual IDE and F11 is the step-into keystroke. However, I am looking at my IDE on monitor 1 and hitting F11 -- when Excel actually has the focus on monitor 2, and presto! One chart non-desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the following two macros in a standard module:

```
Sub DisableF11()
    Application.OnKey "{F11}", "IgnoreKey"
End Sub

Sub IgnoreKey()

End Sub
```

Then run the *DisableF11()* macro.  From this point on, the <kbd>F11</kbd> key will be disabled with the Excel application.

**Notes:**

1. this is at the application level only
2. the change is not permanent.
3. it is equally easy to restore the <kbd>F11</kbd> key via a macro
4. the disable can be made automatic by calling *DisableF11()* from a workbook open event macro

Answer (score 2):

Usually I put stuff like this in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "{F11}"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F11}", ""
End Sub
```

Thus, on open, it is disabled and on close it is enabled back.